# jest.spyOn not called

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to test this component using jest and enzyme in react native:

```
export class MyItem extends PureComponent {

    _onDelete = () => {
        console.log('Deleting !')
    }

    _renderSwpItem = () => {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity id="delete" onPress={this._onDelete}>
                <Icon name="delete" size={50} color={Colors.white}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>     
        )
    }
    ...
}
```

So far I wrote:

```
describe('Testing MyItem', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow( <MyItem />)

    it('_renderSwptItem press works', () => {
        const instance = wrapper.instance()
        const swpWrapper = shallow(instance._renderSwpItem())
        const deletePressSpy = jest.spyOn(instance, '_onDelete')
        swpWrapper.find('#delete').simulate('press')
        expect(deletePressSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
    })
})
```

I can see in the log `Deleting !` but `expect(deletePressSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` fails. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that calling spyOn **before** calling `shallow(instance._renderSwpItem())` does the trick. Not sure why thought...